# Is there any way we can get the snapshot of failed Test cases in Jasmine Allure reporter

Tags: protractor, allure

I wanted to take screenshot for failed test cases only. Currently Allure take screenshot for all tests passed or fail.

Also i tried `jasmine.getenv().currentSpec.Results()`
But this is not supported in Jasmine2 framework.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-reporter
https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-reporter#capture-only-failed-specs-optional

Comment: ADD `var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
   reportOnlyFailedSpecs: false,
   captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true
});`

Comment: This is another reporter. But i want to add to my Allure reporter only and not to use any otehr NPM package

Comment: https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html#section-suiteDone